# Cannot add more than one UIBarButtonItem to RightBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

This used to work in previous versions of Xamarin, but now I cannot add more than one right UIBarButtonItem to my UIViewController NavigationItem. I've checked all the relevant questions here and elsewhere and this still does not work for me.

Here's my code:

```
var addButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, ((object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{

}));

var pauseButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, ((object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{

}));

this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = new UIBarButtonItem[] { addButton, pauseButton };
```

Any suggestions would be welcome as I've tried targeting different iOS versions with no success. Is there an extra setting I haven't looked into?

Answer (score 1):

**Simply add this code:**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

let firstRightButton = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setImage(UIImage (named: "ChatTab"), for: .normal)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35.0, height: 35.0)
//button.addTarget(target, action: nil, for: .touchUpInside)
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: firstRightButton)

let secondRightButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
button2.setImage(UIImage (named: "ActivityTab"), for: .normal)
button2.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35.0, height: 35.0)
//button.addTarget(target, action: nil, for: .touchUpInside)
let barButtonItem2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: secondRightButton)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [barButtonItem, barButtonItem2]
```